# Generating a Word doc with an image embedded into it over SSL in JAVA

Tags: java, ssl, ms-word, doc

Here is some code snippet to give you an idea of what I got so far. I can output the Word document fine this way. I can also access the image via the URL in the browser, but the Word documents src does not appear to be hitting the servlet(according to some logs I have).

ExportServlet.java
`

```
    response.setContentType("application/ms-word");

    String imageUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() +
                      ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath() +
                      "/ExportImage";

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'
    xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'
    xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml'
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>
    <head>
            <title>Exported Documents</title>

            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
           <xml>
           <w:WordDocument>
           <w:View>Print</w:View>
           <w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>
           <w:DoNotOptimizeForBrowser/>
           <w:BreakWrappedTables/>
           </w:WordDocument>
           </xml>
           <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src=\"" + imageUrl + "\">
    </body>
</html>")
    out.flush();
```

`

ExportImage.java

```
      Logger.log("getting Image");
      ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
        String filename = servletContext.getRealPath("myImage.gif");
        response.setContentType(
                servletContext.getMimeType(filename));
        File file = new File(filename);
        response.setContentLength((int)file.length());

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        // Copy the contents of the file to the output stream
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        while ((count = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, count);
        }
        in.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried creating the file with Word itself, using that URL as the image?

Comment: I assume you've verified that the image URL you've constructed in Java is exactly what you expect it to be?  Beyond that, there are multiple possible failure points here-- is the client actually requesting the image? (e.g. is the document constructed correctly) Or is the client requesting it but the servlet doesn't see the request? (URL format, or some security settings, but seems unlikely).

Comment: I can hit the servlet directly via browser and it is fine. The problem is with Word itself. For some reason, Word cannot make a request over https. I did what extraneon said and constructed the document from scratch and it showed that Word is just not capable of doing so. At least, not that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Would another suitable approach be to generate the document completely on the server (with the image embedded already) and stream that to the requestor instead of trying to get the doc to do a separate https fetch?  If so, [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) and [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) can produce documents for you in doc format with images.